# QGIS Browser application

Tags: qgis-browser

I have installed QGIS 3.2 in Windows & Ubuntu OS for the first time. 'Late comer of course'.
I cannot find the usual "standalone" QGIS Browser application installed. However, I can access QGIS Browser panel within QGIS Desktop - no problem.

Does QGIS 3 comes with 'standalone" QGIS Browser application and, if so, how do I access it?